# form going to folder selection not file and clearing cache?

Tags: php, html

I'm using code like 
form action="task/taskA.php" method="post"
input detail ...
input type="submit" value="Masuk"
for my login screen,
but sometimes it stop in file view,

Index of /testingAbdullah
Parent Directory etc ...

with url still the login page (if I remember correctly), 
what happen here ?
I'm using xampp, php,

And sometimes, I need to clear the cache with ccleaner because it won't load the data placed in tabs.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: **unclear what you're asking**

Comment: It sounds like your webserver isn't properly resolving `task/taskA.php`, and is instead trying to load the parent folder. Are you sure you have the form pointing to `taskA.php` and not just `taskA`? That would attempt to look for a folder.

Comment: it's  action="task/taskA.php", and it didn't happen everytime, just sometimes, I was using edge,